# Probability Rules proof

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

How to proof this?

$$\mathbb{P}(A' \cup B') = [\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)']$$

because when I draw it, it does not look same. Or did I do it wrong?

[image]

Comment: On the left you have drawn $(A \cup B)'$ not $ A' \cup B'$.

Comment: You are doing a wrong picture. See https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uVS1kCqNQPc/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: The union of complements, $A'\cup B'$, is every thing not in A *or* everything not in B.  Some things not in A are things in B and some things in A are things not in B. These are included in the union.  The only things excluded from the union are those which are in both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your Venn diagram should look like this.The shaded region is the set $A'\cup B'$, equivalently  $(A\cap B)'.$